# How to get url of a post from admin panel

Tags: permalinks, hooks, urls

I want to get post url from the back end edit post page, 
the edit post url is : www.ddd.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit
the real post is: www.ddd.com/wp/?p=1

since the user can edit permalink, i need some wordpress parametrs so it will be constant.

Looking for this answer:

```
 global $post;
 get_permalink($post->ID);
```

thx all

Comment: Are you referring to the post url you see on admin edit screen or the url on the site frontend?

Comment: Can you add some more details on what you need and why so that we can look into the situation better and try and help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `ID` of the post you're editing like this:

```
//currently edited post id 
$cep_id = $_GET['post'];
//permalink
get_permalink( $cep_id );
```

This is and can only work if your editing an existing/saved post. It won't and can't work on »Add New«-Pages, because the post you're going to add isn't saved to the database yet, after »Publish« has been pressed one gets redirected to the actual »Edit«-Page and the above is possible.

Comment: this what I looked for, thx

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for the post edit url for admin end and you have the post id (suppose **`$post_id`**) with you, then you can use the following code for getting the url.

```
$post_url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post_id ) . '&action=edit';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'current_screen' hook and `get_permalink()`:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function ( $screen ) {
    $url = get_permalink( $screen->id );
    // ...
} );
```

This hook receives a WP_Screen_Object with misc. information about the current admin screen the user is browsing. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/current_screen and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink for details.

Comment: get_permalink( $screen->id ) worked great